# Groupby with condition, include 0 occurrences

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with week's worth of mobile pings. I want to know how many times on average do people go to gym, based on a group they're in, or based on where they're from.

The 'problem' is, some people never go to the gym, and I want to include those too, otherwise the average gets very skewed.

[image]

When I do a normal groupby though, 0 occurences aren't counted. I also need to include a condition that Ping_coordinates==Local_gym_coordinates.

What I want to get is:

[image]

What I've tried so far is:

```
df.groupby('ID').filter(lambda x: ((x['Ping_coordinates'] == x['Local_gym_coordinates']))).mean()

df.groupby('ID').filter(lambda x: ((x['Ping_coordinates'] == x['Local_gym_coordinates']).all()))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
out1 = df['Ping_coordinates'].eq(df['Local_gym_coordinates']).groupby(df['ID']).sum()

out2 = out1.mean()
```

Comment: Yes thank you, that does what I want it to do. But what if I want to see averages for each group and each town? Before what I did was
df2=df.groupby(['ID', 'Group', 'Home_coordinates', 'Local_gym_coordinates', 'Ping_coordinates'])['Date'].count().reset_index()

df2.groupby(['Home_coordinates','Group'])['Date'].mean().unstack().reset_index()
temp=df2.groupby(['ID','Group'])['Date'].mean().unstack().reset_index()
cols=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q']
for i in cols:
    print(temp[i].mean())